# How to create custom value types in OData?

Tags: .net, odata, type-safety, value-type

I have an OData API and was wondering what is the proper way of adding support for a custom value-type/strong type object so that it is recognized during serialziation, desserialization and metadata-generation.

Say for example that I have a custom `Temperature` type, that is able to parse strings like `32°F`, `50F` (no degree symbol), `40°C` (Celsius) etc. Depending on the value and scale, an internal value is set in the class so that it can later be compared to other `Temperature` instances.

Now, I want to be able to expose a property of type `Temperature` in my OData model and make it behave like the custom string type. It should

- Be able to be deserialized from the text representation when posting data
- Be able to be serialized into the text representation when getting data
- Be able to be used in filter expressions as its string form
- Be able to be used as part of a composite key, or be the primary key itself

I wasn't able to find any clear extension point in the OData .Net library about this, nor have I heard of any such support in the OASIS spec.

I know a few built-in types in .Net have such support implemented natively, like `DateTime` or the spatial types.

Is there a way to add support for custom classes/structs like this, and if so, how does one go about it? Same goes for .Net types not currently handled natively, like `Uri`.

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this issue? I have run into the same issue when trying to use Ulids as primary keys with OData

Comment: I see you already replied on the issue I created as well. I have in the past made some custom types work but it is extremely hacky: you have to rely on a dummy implementation of `ISpatial` and handle the value as a value type using another custom interface I don't recall now. All-in-all, clearly not the intended usage of the API.

Comment: I spent a little while stepping through the ASP.NET Core OData source code and it seems that there is, unfortunately, currently no extensibility point which would allow custom primitive types to be used. As best as I can tell, the full list of primitive types is contained in a private static dictionary in this class: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Shared/Formatter/EdmLibHelpers.cs

Comment: Any success on the topic? We have a similar issue with OData - introduced custom enums implemented as C# immutable objects. Works fine with EF Core thanks to the custom  ValueConverter implementation which performs conversion between custom objects and GUIDs, but we got stuck with OData because we cannot represent our custom class literal in the filter query.

Comment: Not yet @Roman. There is an equivalent question that I raised in one of the OData repos [here](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/1967) that had more discussions going, but remains unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

From a protocol perspective, TypeDefinitions are intended to solve this type of scenario. They are supported in ODL/ModelBuilder, but not in WebApi OData 7x. AspNetCoreOData 8.x adds support for custom type mapping, which could provide a solution.

I have moved the original issue to [AspNetCoreOData](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/732), in order to validate support for this scenario.